# Android setId() cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I'm trying to programmatically set the ID of a TextView simply using the line

```
titleView.setId(R.id.installedTitle);
```

but I get an error at this line that states:

**"installedTitle cannot be resolved or is not a field"**

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that you have that id defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have (maybe) not cleaned your Project, so it may be possible that your R File has not been generated. You may also have some errors in your Project (xml files) so the R wont get generated aswell.  You may also not have used setContentView() before and loaded the Layout and/or the ID is not in your layout.